# Error message while trying to install most recent version of terra package

Tags: terra

I am trying to install the latest version of the terra package in R on a macOS Ventura 13.3.1. The installation failed showing the following error message.

> install.packages("terra", repos = "https://rspatial.r-universe.dev")

Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
C/C++/Fortran: ‘terra’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) y
installing the source package ‘terra’

checking PROJ: checking whether PROJ and sqlite3 are available for linking:... no
configure: error: libproj or sqlite3 not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/terra’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Best!

Kenny

Answer (score 1):

try
https://github.com/rspatial/terra

> install.packages("terra", type = "source", configure.args = "--with-proj-lib=$(brew --prefix)/lib/")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).